# How to update the element in nested arrays in mongoose using $set and filter method?

Tags: node.js, arrays, mongoose, handlebars.js, nested-loops

I am trying this code to update all the `bool` element in `Bigpaths` array nested in `Addtasks` array of `User` schema. But I am unable to see the changes in MongoDB.  Although in console it is printing "bool" string. Where I am stucking?

```
  router.post('/api/update/:id',function(req,res,next){
      
  User.updateMany( {"Addtasks.Id4AddtasksBigpaths":req.params.id},
                  { $set: { "Bigpaths.$[elem].bool" : true } },
                  { arrayFilters: [ { "elem.Id4AddtasksBigpaths": req.params.id} ] },
                    function (error, success) {
                      if(error)
                      {
                        console.log(error);
                      }
                      else {
                        console.log("bool");
                      }
                    }
    )
})
```

This is my Addtasks Array inside User Collection :

```
[{
    "Id4AddtasksBigpaths" : "m9b8mpyn2iby$s",
    "clientName" : "Vikas Yadav",
    "deadline" : "Set Deadline",
    "assignee" : "Assign",
    "displayLock" : "none",
    "displayDelete" : "inline",
    "commonID" : "o5xz13ffxq8",
    "status" : "Requirement Completed",
    "Date" : "Sat Sep 19 2020 00:00:05 GMT+0530 (India Standard Time)",
    "exampleRadios" : "option1",
    "otherdetails" : "trhr",
    "website" : "nmbn.com",
    "keywords" : "anxiety disorders for children, anxiety disorders for adults",
    "words" : 543,
    "topic" : "How to build the empire?",
    "_id" : ObjectId("5f64fcad7c8b1b252c441360"),
    "Bigpaths4Clients" : [],
    "Bigpaths" : [ 
        {
            "path" : "public\\files\\Screenshot_2016-11-25-23-19-51.png",
            "name" : "Screenshot_2016-11-25-23-19-51.png",
            "Id4AddtasksBigpaths" : "m9b8mpyn2iby$s",
            "uniqueId" : "8q9tcy2w3k3u$id",
            "bool" : ""
        },
       {
            "path" : "public\\files\\Screenshot_2017-11-25-23-21-51.png",
            "name" : "Screenshot_2017-11-25-23-21-51.png",
            "Id4AddtasksBigpaths" : "m9b8mpyn2iby$s",
            "uniqueId" : "9q9tcz2w3k3u$id",
            "bool" : ""
        }
    ]
}]
```

Full User Schema:

```
var userSchema = new mongoose.Schema({
  email: {
    type: String,
    unique: true,
    required: true
  },
  name: {
    type: String,
    required: true
  },
  tag: {
    type: String
    },

  hash: String,
  salt: String,

  Addtasks : [{
    topic: String,
    words: Number,
    keywords: String,
    website: String,
    otherdetails: String,
    exampleRadios: String,
    Date: String,
    Bigpaths:[],
    status:String,
    fileName: String,
    commonID:String,
    Bigpaths4Clients:[],
    displayDelete:String,
    displayLock:String,
    assignee:String,
    deadline:String,
    completion:String,
    clientName:String,
    Id4AddtasksBigpaths:String
  }]

});

userSchema.methods.setPassword = function(password) {
  this.salt = crypto.randomBytes(16).toString('hex');
  this.hash = crypto.pbkdf2Sync(password, this.salt, 1000, 64, 'sha1').toString('hex');
};

userSchema.methods.validPassword = function(password) {
  var hash = crypto.pbkdf2Sync(password, this.salt, 1000, 64, 'sha1').toString('hex');
  return this.hash === hash;
};

module.exports = mongoose.model('User', userSchema);
```

Express Updated Code:

```
router.route('/profile/view/:id')
.get(function(req, res, next) {
    Editable.findOne({userId: req.params.id}, function (err, dataEditable) {
      if (dataEditable){
    console.log("if condition");
    User.findOne({_id: req.user.id}, function(err, dataUser) {
      if (dataUser) {
        console.log("two");
          dataUser.Addtasks.forEach(element => {
            if(element._id == req.params.id)
            {
            console.log("userID and paramID got matched in if condition");
            res.render('viewTask',{mainData: element,  hiding:true});
            console.log("viewTask rendered with editing option");
          }
        });
          }
          else {
          res.render('error');
        }
        });
      }
          else {
            console.log("else condition");
            User.findOne({_id: req.user.id}, function(err, data) {
            data.Addtasks.forEach(element => {
              if(element._id == req.params.id)
              {
              console.log("userID and paramID got matched in else condition");

User.updateMany( {"Addtasks.Id4AddtasksBigpaths":element.Id4AddtasksBigpaths},
              { $set: { "Addtasks.$.Bigpaths.$[elem].bool" : true } },
              { arrayFilters: [ { "elem.Id4AddtasksBigpaths": element.Id4AddtasksBigpaths} ] },
                function (error, success) {
                  if(error)
                  {
                    console.log(error);
                  }
                  else {
                    console.log("bool");
                  }
                }
)
              res.render('viewTask', {mainData: element, edit:"readonly", hiding:false});
              console.log("viewTask rendered with read-only");
            }
          });
          })
        }
  })
})
```

Dependencies:

```
"dependencies": {
    "body-parser": "~1.16.0",
    "bytenode": "^1.1.6",
    "cookie-parser": "~1.4.3",
    "debug": "~2.6.0",
    "express": "~4.14.1",
    "express-handlebars": "^5.1.0",
    "express-session": "^1.15.1",
    "express-validator": "^3.2.1",
    "express-zip": "^3.0.0",
    "gridfs-stream": "^1.1.1",
    "hbs": "~4.0.1",
    "js-alert": "^1.0.4",
    "mongoose": "^4.13.21",
    "mongoose-update-if-current": "^1.4.0",
    "morgan": "~1.7.0",
    "multer": "^1.4.2",
    "node-downloader-helper": "^1.0.13",
    "nodemailer": "^3.1.8",
    "passport": "^0.3.2",
    "passport-local": "^1.0.0",
    "popups": "^1.1.3",
    "req-flash": "0.0.3",
    "serve-favicon": "~2.3.2",
    "sweetalert": "^2.1.2"
  }
```

Comment: Note: Id4AddtasksBigpaths is in both main Addtasks array and in Bogpaths array as well respectively. So in Arrayfilters I am referring to the Bigpath's Id4AddtasksBigpaths.

Answer (score 1):

Because your `Bigpaths` is inside `Addtasks` array so in the update, you need to use [positional $ operator](https://docs.mongodb.com/manual/reference/operator/update/positional/) to tell mongo which Addtasks need update:

```
 User.updateMany( {"Addtasks.Id4AddtasksBigpaths":req.params.id},
              { $set: { "Addtasks.$.Bigpaths.$[elem].bool" : true } },
              { arrayFilters: [ { "elem.Id4AddtasksBigpaths": req.params.id} ] },...
```

Refer to your updated code, look like you are updating only one `User` so `findOneAndUpdate()` would be better in this case. You can try modify the code in else block to:

```
User.findOneAndUpdate({ _id: req.user.id, "Addtasks.Id4AddtasksBigpaths": req.params.id },
      { $set: { "Addtasks.$.Bigpaths.$[elem].bool": true } },
      { arrayFilters: [{ "elem.Id4AddtasksBigpaths": req.params.id }] },
      function (error, doc) {
        if (error) {
          console.log(error);
        }
        else {
          console.log("bool");
          res.render('viewTask', { mainData: element, edit: "readonly", hiding: false });
        }
      }
    )
```

Comment: Now I am getting this error:    errmsg: "No array filter found for identifier 'elem' in path 'Addtasks.$.Bigpaths.$[elem].bool' "  @Cuong

Comment: That's strange, can you show the full user document?

Comment: Updated the full user schema at the bottom. Pls check

Comment: Can you show the updated code also? I tested with this structure in my computer and it worked

Comment: Add the code as well. This arrayfilters code I am using in else condition of GET route only. First I am checking if the data is there in Editable collections or not. If data is there if condition works if it doesnt match then else condition works.

Comment: Which version of mongodb and mongoose are you using?

Comment: "mongoose": "^4.13.21",

Comment: and mongodb version?

Comment: Just updated all dependencies in the answer. pls check

Comment: for mongoDB its 4,2 version

Comment: But it should hve worked with updateMany as well. Dont you think?

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/221739/discussion-between-cuong-le-ngoc-and-biku7).